# As to why or of why

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality

Which one is correct and used universally?

> I don’t owe you an explanation **as to why** I knocked the glass over.
>
> I don’t owe you an explanation **of why** I knocked the glass over.

Is one used more than the other? Does it depend on the country and region?

Thank you!

Comment: Both forms are used in AmE and  BrE, apparently “of why” is the more common between the two. - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=explanation+as+to+why%2C+explanation+of+why&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexplanation%20as%20to%20why%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexplanation%20of%20why%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Why not just why?

Comment: Neither is correct at the expense of the other, nor is either used universally. Why not just *I don't owe you an explanation **for knocking** over the glass*?